# Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand

Tags: flutter, screen-orientation, device-orientation

On one of my flutter pages, I need the screen to set to landscape mode and lock it so it can't rotate into portrait mode, but only on the one page. So need a way to enable this function on-the-fly. Anyone know how to do this?

I would like it to rotate landscape-left or landscape-right, just not into portrait mode.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

First import the services package:

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

This will give you access to the `SystemChrome` class, which `"Controls specific aspects of the operating system's graphical interface and how it interacts with the application."`

When you load the Widget, do something like this:

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

then when I leave the page, put it back to normal like this:

```
@override
dispose(){
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: but seems working on android only https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20124

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. That's very possible, I only tested this on Android.

Comment: nevermind, it can be solved by Platform Channel https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13238#issuecomment-435958221 and i think it will be fixed soon

Comment: Only to appoint that this bug was solved months ago, and this solution works now also on iOS

Comment: From what I see, it is not a good idea to set the preferred orientation in dispose method. The dispose method is not called if you navigate to another route and you intend to go back.

Comment: nice solution... but it seems lagging while moving between screen

Comment: Anyone knows if this is working on iOS now? I have to implement this.

Comment: Is it possible to receive orientation callback even after setting SystemChrome values. I need to set the screen in portrait and need to listen for orientation changes to update some portion of the widget. Any suggestion??

Comment: I don't think this works anymore, as `setPreferredOrientations` returns a `Future` now. You'd probably need to wrap this logic into a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Does this work for the camera as well?  App needs to take photos of things like motorbikes and passports which are better suited to Landscape mode. Written in flutter for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 47):

I would use a simple **mixin** to *lock phone in portrait*. The following solution locks the *entire app in portrait* or *sets specific screens* to portrait while keeping rotation elsewere.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// Forces portrait-only mode application-wide
/// Use this Mixin on the main app widget i.e. app.dart
/// Flutter's 'App' has to extend Stateless widget.
///
/// Call `super.build(context)` in the main build() method
/// to enable portrait only mode
mixin PortraitModeMixin on StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _portraitModeOnly();
    return null;
  }
}

/// Forces portrait-only mode on a specific screen
/// Use this Mixin in the specific screen you want to
/// block to portrait only mode.
///
/// Call `super.build(context)` in the State's build() method
/// and `super.dispose();` in the State's dispose() method
mixin PortraitStatefulModeMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _portraitModeOnly();
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _enableRotation();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

/// blocks rotation; sets orientation to: portrait
void _portraitModeOnly() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}

void _enableRotation() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
}
```

To **block rotation in the entire app** implement `PortraitModeMixin` in the main `App` widget. Remember to call `super.build(context)` in `Widget build(BuildContext context)` method.

```
/// Main App widget
class App extends StatelessWidget with PortraitModeMixin {
  const App();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(),
      home: Text("Block screen rotation example"),
    );
  }
}
```

To **block rotation in a specific screen** implement `PortraitStatefulModeMixin<SampleScreen>` in the specific screen's state. Remember to call `super.build(context)` in the State's `build()` method and `super.dispose()` in `dispose()` method. If your screen is a **StatelessWidget** - simply repeat the App's solution (previous example) i.e. use `PortraitModeMixin`.

```
/// Specific screen
class SampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SampleScreen() : super();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SampleScreenState();
}

class _SampleScreenState extends State<SampleScreen>
    with PortraitStatefulModeMixin<SampleScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Text("Flutter - Block screen rotation example");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
     super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Mixins with such syntax work from Dart 2.1

Comment: I have tried your mixin class - stateless version works just fine, however statefull one throws an exception, once my statefull class calls its disposed method. Note, I call `super.dispose()` within my class. Below is the error:
I/flutter (29686): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
I/flutter (29686): _MultiPlayerAcceptPageState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.
I/flutter (29686): dispose() implementations must always call their superclass dispose() method, to ensure that all the
I/flutter (29686): resources used by the widget are fully released.

Comment: Same exception for stateful version. Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Solved it! If you use Android Studio, this is clearly detectable. It says `dispose()` is annotated as `@mustCallSuper`. This means you need to add `super.dispose()` within the mixin function itself.

Comment: return null; in the mixin throws following error: A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, though a little dated now.  Replace `return null` with `return super.build(context);` in the newer versions of Flutter and it will work just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for application running on iOS or Android ?
I assume "SystemChrome" is only for web?

Answer (score 40):

First, Lock the entire app orientation to Portrait mode.

```
//Do this in main.dart
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
  .then((_) {
runApp(MyApp());
});
```

Second, Go the specific screen where you want to change the orientation.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
]);
```

}

```
@override
void dispose() {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
super.dispose();
}
```

For using SystemChrome you will have to add `'package:flutter/services.dart'`

Comment: what to do in case of stateless widget ?

Comment: You need a stateful widget for access to the lifecycle methods.

Comment: My app normally works on portrait. When I move to LandscapeScreen from HomeScreen, I have set to landscape mode. When I press back, It Loads the HomeScreen in LandscapeScreen mode first and then build it portrait. This happens in less a second.

Comment: no effect on iOS 16 - any ideas

Answer (score 21):

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
    .then((_) {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 7):

import services.dart package and add following code to lock device orientation to portraitUp mode:

```
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

 main() {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
     runApp(MyHomePage());
 }
```

Comment: `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` made this solution work for me. Good catch!

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it could not work due to null info about orientation.
You can use it simply like this:

```
import services.dart


void main() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]
     )
        .then((_) {
          runApp(new MyApp());
        });
    }
```

// wait for settings screen orientation after initiating app and -> then lock orientation

Answer (score 5):

**Important for iOS**.

- Enable the orientation in in info.plist file. for Example [image]

**Steps**

- Set the orientation in main.dart file. In my case, My application is only support for portrait except the one screen so i need to set the portrait mode at first time. for Example

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,]);
```

- Add the following code in that screen which you need to rotate.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }
  @override
  dispose(){
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Simple way to lock screen orientation in whole app**

- Add `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` to the start of `main.dart` file.
- Create `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations();` method to disable Screen rotation in Widget build area of `MyApp` class just before the `return` part.
- Specify the orientation using `[DeviceOrientation.<orientation-type>]` in arguments of the method.

Use one of the following in place of `<orientation-type>` :

1. `portraitUp`
2. `portraitDown`
3. `landscapeLeft`
4. `landscapeRight`

**Example Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' ;
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);
 
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen Orientation"),
        ),
        body: Container(
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

import `services.dart` and your `void main` function should be like:

```
void main(){

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
       [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
       .then((_){
           runApp(MyApp());
       }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest file in main folder under activity tag set android:screenOrientation = "portrait"

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation = "portrait">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use orientation_helper for this https://pub.dev/packages/orientation_helper . It’s main goal is to set orientation for each screen in an app.

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer to use hooks

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

useOrientation(List<DeviceOrientation> orientations) {
  useEffect(
    () {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(orientations);
      return () {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        ]);
      };
    },
  );
}
```

Use it like:

```
class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  void build(BuildContext context) {

    useOrientation([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the preferred orientation in the flutter.

```
// import this package
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// Lock the orientation to Portrait Only
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(MyApp()));
```

You can also add Preferred Orientations in the `setPreferredOrientations` list like `[DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]`

Below are the orientation you can set:

```
/// If the device shows its boot logo in portrait, then the boot logo is shown
  /// in [portraitUp]. Otherwise, the device shows its boot logo in landscape
  /// and this orientation is obtained by rotating the device 90 degrees
  /// clockwise from its boot orientation.
  portraitUp,

  /// The orientation that is 90 degrees clockwise from [portraitUp].
  ///
  /// If the device shows its boot logo in landscape, then the boot logo is
  /// shown in [landscapeLeft].
  landscapeLeft,

  /// The orientation that is 180 degrees from [portraitUp].
  portraitDown,

  /// The orientation that is 90 degrees counterclockwise from [portraitUp].
  landscapeRight,
```

Ref: https://greymag.medium.com/flutter-orientation-lock-portrait-only-c98910ebd769

Answer (score -1):

In GetX, you need to use GetBuilder like this example:

```dart
    final Controller ctrl = Get.find();

    GetBuilder<Controller>(
      initState: (_) => ctrl.setLandscape(),
      dispose: (_) => ctrl.setPortrait(),
      builder: (code) => Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.zero,
          alignment: Alignment.Center,
          child: const SizedBox(),
       ),
    ),
```

In Controller file:

```dart
    class Controller extends GetxController {
      RxBool isLandscape = false.obs;

      Future<void> setLandscape() async {
        if (isLandscape.isTrue) {
          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
          update();
        }
      }
      
      Future<void> setPortrait() async {
        if (isLandscape.isFalse) {
          await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
          update();
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope this solution will answer developers who use GetX as their main state management. Good luck, bro! God blesses you all.