# flutter- How to know the device is DeviceOrientation is up or down?

Tags: dart, flutter

When I am rotating screen its rotates camera along with the screen, so I am getting
Inverted camera screen.

```
return new AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
    child: new CameraPreview(controller),
  );
```

Comment: Someone had pretty much the same issue as you have. Check out this link. He solved it in a plugin that accesses the device orientation via native code: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17215

Answer (score 15):

You can build responsive apps using OrientationBuilder

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode, or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
);
```

or

```
Orientation currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
if(currentOrientation == Orientation.portrait){
    /* ... */
}
```

To enforce a particular orientation see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322184/9664127

other useful links:

https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/orientation/

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/DeviceOrientation-class.html

https://medium.com/@kr1uz/how-to-restrict-device-orientation-in-flutter-65431cd35113

**Updated**

Flutter does not currently support 'orientation sides', but this plugin may help in that area
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/native_device_orientation

Comment: There's also `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation`

Comment: I think that you are missing the actual question because `OrientationBuilder` does not tell you whether potrait is "up" or "down".

Comment: @RémiRousselet thanks for the suggestion, `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` could really come in handy

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot, lol thanks, had to read the question again. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/native_device_orientation

(I'm having some issues with iOS - reporting opposite orientation, but this can be worked around)