# Flutter "App keeps stopping" message when I try to open it in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, mobile, dart

I'm currently trying to force the app to be always used in portrait mode through the following code:

```
Future main() async {
  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  runApp(
    HomePage()
  );
}
```

When I open the App with the tablet already in portrait it works perfectly but if I close the App, turn the tablet to landscape and try to open it again the message "App keeps stopping" is show and the App wont open until I use the tablet in portrait mode again. It does not throw any exception or error in the terminal when the message is shown and the same error happens both in the emulator as in a real device.

How do I make it possible for the App to open and be used in portrait mode without prohibiting the user from opening it with the tablet in landscape mode? Or at least, how do I prevent this message from being shown?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand see here.

Comment: try changing in init() method of your start page.

Comment: I have tried it but sadly the error persisted. thanks for the attention anyway

Comment: Are you using apple tablet?

Comment: No, its a Samsung A10