# How to prevent device rotation only for certain classes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, flutter-layout, screen-orientation

I'm developing a Flutter app, and I need to prevent the device rotation only in some classes, while keeping it working in others. I now how to disable the rotation globally in the app, but how to disable it only in certain classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using something like this in your widget:

```dart
// to lock in landscape view
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}

@override
dispose() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
}
```

The fact that `initState()` and `dispose()` are used means that you have to use a `StatefulWidget` if that wasn't the case already.

Comment: Guillaume Roux - This restriction is also applied on `child screens` / `Navigator.push screens` which is not good solution for me. Any other suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.