# Flutter device orientation issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hope you are all well.
I want to lock orientation of screen in flutter. I am writing following code..

```
 @override
 void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
     super.initState();
}
```

It is woriking fine. But when I go to the other screen and again Navigate back to that screen, then it does not work and do not lock the orientation.
So kindly help.

Comment: I do believe you will have to change fixed orientation in android or iOS folders. for example in iOS you have to go to runner file and change orientation to whatever you want

Comment: I want to change orientation at every page some to b portrait and and some to be landscape..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand)

Comment: Then the case is you want some views allways portrait and others allways landscape?

Comment: yes of course this is what i want to achieve

Comment: Then it's lot easier, in your case I would choose to lock portrait, in the views you always want landscape just design the view in that way (I mean designing the view to look like landscape even if in reality is in portrait, I hope you catch my idea).

Comment: @Muhammad Haven't you read the linked page above? `initState()` is called only once, so you need to set the orientation again in `dispose()` of the next screen. Doing it instead when the next screen is popped would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You may use SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setPreferredOrientations.html

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);
```

Let me know if it works, I know I was able to lock an orientation with this, I don't know if you can change whenever you want but from the api I don't see any limitation.