# Programmatically change orientation

Tags: flutter

Flutter has a built in method called `setPreferredOrientations()`. From my understanding, this function locks the orientations set in the arguments. I would instead just like to change the orientation, but not lock it. My use case is as follows:

- Users can view an image in fullscreen mode
- Many users leave device rotation off in their system settings
- To avoid the effort of having to enable and disable device rotation to rotate the image to landscape, I would instead like a "rotate" button that will rotate the layout for the user (and allow them to rotate it back), rather than needing to physically rotate their device.

Any ideas on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Apurv Jha's answer should work. I also think it's stolen from here: [Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand).

Have you tried this: you might want to use the code from `initState` in a different place. For example, in `onPressed` or `onTap` parameters for widgets. Then create a state that indicates whether the device was rotated or not. It might be a simple bool or some way to get the device rotation at the moment of button press. Then depending on the state set the orientation to be different from one on the state and update the state.

Comment: The reason orientation gets locked is that it runs on `initState`. If you don't run it there, orientation will follow user's settings as usual. But make sure that this whole thing is wrapped in a StatefulWidget with a correct scope. You probably want to include only image viewer in your StatefulWidget.

Comment: Ah interesting, wasn't aware that that could affect things. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool variable flag instead of changing the setPreferredOrientations() arguments in the dispose method.

Whenever the user clicks on the roation button check the variable if the default value is true then set the variable to false and set the orientation to landscape and if its value is not equal to the default value change the orientation to portrait.

```
if(flag == true)
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
else
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
```

and in the dispose method set arguments to default.