# Flutter dynamic screen rotation

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to dynamically do screen rotation in Flutter for few of the screens and not affect to other screens?

So i tried two ways, with mixins. (This way [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304877/9384156) ). It works initially, for the first enter and leave screen, but when I do re-run again some of screen which should be landscape again, it's fixed in portrait and thats all, until i re-run the app.

And tried directly, with setting preferred orientation. (This way [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322184/9384156) This way mess-up whole app even if i just unlock rotation on build/initState (tried both) on one screen, and lock it on same screen on dispose.

For example, i need camera screen rotated with whole UI, and i have screen to edit the image, and i need that screen in the portrait, and there problems shows up.

UPDATE: So here is the link with code with mixins try. I created mixin which enables rotation in that screen, and on dispose, lock rotation again. [CODE](https://www.codepile.net/pile/B15q7D15)

And code here:

```
mixin RotationEnabledStatefulModeMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on 
State<T> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
_enableRotation();
return null;
}

@override
void dispose() {
_portraitModeOnly();
 print("RotationEnabledStatefulModeMixin -> disposed!");
}
}

void _portraitModeOnly() {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
 DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
 DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
 ]);
}

void _enableRotation() {
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
 }



 //this is screen where i need landscape only
  class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 final CameraDescription camera;

 TakePictureScreen(
  {Key key, @required this.camera, this.report, this.sectionIndex})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> with 
RotationEnabledStatefulModeMixin<TakePictureScreen>{
CameraController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
     super.initState();
}

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
    
}

@override
void dispose() {
_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: These methods should work. Please share some code where you are setting the preferred orientations.

Comment: Hey, thanks for feedback! I updated my post with link to code. @Lee3

Comment: Try calling `_enableRotation()` in `initState()` instead of `build()`.