# How can I make my App work in Landscape mode too?

Tags: flutter, dart

my app works in portrait mode, but in landscape mode it gets strange.

I tried it with the following:

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    final bool isLandscape = orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      primary: !isLandscape,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BottomPlate(),
            // TopPlate(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
} ```

but that doesn't work.


 [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBh56.png
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand