# How to keep app in portrait mode only in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want my app in Portrait Mode only as it is designed so, but app rotates by default.
The app is in Flutter Framework.
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand)

Comment: @Nagual yeah, I could not find it at that time, yeah it is correct answer

Answer (score 26):

In your `lib/main.dart` file,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'path_to_your_app_widget.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

In addition to the answer above, add this code to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` to avoid a peculiar glitch when launching your app from landscape

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.orientation_lock_example">
<application ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        ...
        />
        ... 
    </activity>
    ... 
</application>
```

For iOS, you could open `ios/Runner/Info.plist` as a text file and then find the key `UISupportedInterfaceOrientation`. Edit it and leave only the `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` string

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Follow this one. Native solutions are always better

Comment: Thank you I am working on android so it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in your `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'path_to_your_app_widget.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(AppWidget());
}
```

Comment: The answer of above is same but then also thank you for helping

Comment: @ManavSarkar Yeah, that's cause he answered after I did, lol. And I recommend you follow his answer, as explained in the comment there.