# Flutter dynamic orientation for each screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to add dynamic orientation for each screen??
I need a few of my screens must be in portrait and a few of them in the landscape...
I have used

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
```

and

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
```

for different screen.. But it doesnot solve my problem... The first oreintation is added to all the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is to give the user a option to choose a orientationn by defining

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
```

It always sets the current orientation as the one in which your device is right now but will also allow the app to work with second or third orientation if it changes through the device itself.

what you are supposed to do is to set this to a specific orientation like

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
```

Now since you want different orientations for different screens you can set the same using the above command but with the desired orientation of your choice on each and every screen.

Again if you want to make your app more interactive then you can always get the current orientation using

```
MediaQuery.of(context).orientation
```

and later deciding at each screen whether you want to change the orientation or not.

You can find more info [here](https://dev.to/mightytechno/how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-flutter-32c1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer...well here is the actual answer I needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322184/10245224