# Lock landscape, enable only on specific views

Tags: flutter

I want to force portrait mode in my app, I am using the settings below. However I have a view, that I must enable landscape on, is there way for this to only work on all views except specific one that I want? I don't want to paste this in every widget throughout the app.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
```

On the view I want landscape, I have an if that checks if the view is landscape or portrait, but it wont render to landscape with settings above.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322184/15117201)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your app is completely in "Portrait". What you had will work. Now, you want a specific screen to be either portrait/landscape or only landscape. Then you can configure separately for that one screen (say Screen2).

You are in Screen1 and want to go to Screen2 (which should be in landscape).

```dart
// screen2
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  setLandscape(); // set to portrait
}

@override
dispose(){
  setPortrait(); // set to portrait
  super.dispose();
}

// function changes to landscape
setLandscape() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      // below 2 lines are based on your requirement
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}

// function changes to portrait
setPortrait() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}
```

If you don't have to navigate to new screen, this would work fine

But problem would be when navigating to the Screen3 from Screen2 where Screen3 should be portrait (not landscape). You can change it when navigating and revert it back to landscape when popping.

```dart
// screen2

// navigates safely to next screen changing to portrait and
// reverts to landscape when popped to this screen
navigateTo(<navigate screen>) {
   setPortrait();
   Navigator.of(context)
       .push(<navigate screen>)
       .then(() => setLandscape()); // then completes when pop() returns to this page
}
```